# How to launch Chrome Canary in Windows 8 mode

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I want to run Chrome Canary in Windows 8 Mode. I know this has to do with setting it as the default browser, which I don't mind doing, but isn't an option within Chrome Canary. How can I launch it as a metro/"modern" ui app? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Control Panel > Default Programs > Set your default programs.*
Click on Google Chrome Canary and select *"Set this program as default"*.
Close and reopen the browser and wait.  The [Metro app](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/google-sneaks-chrome-os-interface-secretely-windows-8/) should look like the desktop on Chromebooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can only run a browser in "metro" mode if it is set as default browser, this is a Windows 8 limitation. You have no choice here.

Comment: Might also be worth explicitly pointing out that canary can never be the default browser